# How to open port connect https on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

My website is using **https** and i using `AWS EC2` for this website.

I opened a new port in this server. but in my website, when I connect to `EC2`, I got an **error** as below.

> Mixed Content: The page at `<URL>` was loaded over *HTTPS*, but requested an insecure `XMLHttpRequest` endpoint `<URL>`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over *HTTPS*.

I have a question that can I setting `EC2` to open new port can connect using https.

Update
My server URL is: http://ec1-1-111-1-111.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

I want to access as https://ec1-1-111-1-111.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

I don't know how to do it?
1. I must create private key, certificate and install it in server?
or
2. I don't need to step 1. only setting in AWS.

What is correct in 1 or 2?

**NEW UPDATE 8/8/2019**

Thank you. My domain configured SSL. I can access [link]https://example.com without problem. How ever when I access [link]https://example.com:8888/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MnlKWyJ it said that ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. What is problem in here?

Comment: Your website is trying to fetch some assets using HTTP instead of HTTPS. This is why you are seeing that  message. It is all about your application code, not the ports.

Comment: however, I can not access https server. I think it's problem. Ex: https://ecXX-XX-XXX-XX-188.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/  I got an error is NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: You have to issue a certificate in ACM and associate it with your own domain (*.mydomain.com) in Route53. Then create a CNAME record that points to the EC2 DNS name (e.g.  app.mydomain.com --> CNAME --> ecXX-XX-XXX-XX-188.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com).

Comment: Thank you. My domain configured SSL. I can access https://example.com without problem. How ever when I access https://example.com:8888/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MnlKWyJ it said that ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. What is problem in here?

Comment: @erhanux I resolved it. Thank you so much